# How would I make a Pricing Sheet using Google Sheets or Excel that Automatically calculates the price of a project based on text options?

Tags: excel, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I am trying to create a google sheet or excel spreadsheet that can automatically calculate the price of a project. I am currently using `=VLOOKUP` to pull numeric values from a separate page. My issue is that I cannot figure out how to get the formulas to work the equation I want them to. I am able to reliably pull single values, but not add any other values with them to produce a total. I keep receiving a formula parse error. I tried using the following formula, but would not be surprised to find out I was way off. `=SUMPRODUCT((=VLOOKUP(A3,PriceTable!A$2:B$5,2,0)*(B3+C3)+(=VLOOKUP(A3,PriceTable!G$2:H$5,2,0))))`

I have included a link to the sheet as well as the basic equation I would like done. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Link: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1aT9NrsJUEIubiXCBDgZRNdddKtmPbFAt9opQS-f6FJ8/edit?usp=sharing
Equation I want done: (column names) A(B+C)+D=E

Comment: I don't know who jumped on the sheet 2 minutes after I posted this question, But thank you! You were incredibly helpful in not only getting it to work, but showing me how it worked!

Answer (score 1):

This is what was put into the sheet and it does exactly what I wanted. I am unsure of who the person who helped me is.

`={"Total"; ArrayFormula(IF(A2:A="",,IFERROR(1/(1/(IFNA(VLOOKUP(A2:A, PriceTable!A:B, 2, 0))*(B2:B+C2:C)+IFNA(VLOOKUP(D2:D, PriceTable!C:D, 2, 0)))))))}`

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
=INDEX(IF(A2:A="",,IFERROR(1/(1/(
 IFNA(VLOOKUP(A2:A, H:I, 2, 0))*(B2:B+C2:C)+
 IFNA(VLOOKUP(D2:D, J:K, 2, 0)))))))
```